# Filter result using jquery or JS from an existing value set

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have been trying create filters for the array returned on my page and have been trying this for a while and i have exactly same problem as this thread : [Filtering with checkboxes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796472/filtering-with-checkboxes-using-jquery)

**Why the above thread was not helpful** : main reason is m not very good in JS and jQuery, so had difficulty in understanding the 2nd method (of the accepted answer) and first one dint worked

**What i have done so far :** Going by the help on this thread [How to dynamically filter content using checkboxes? - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498021/how-to-dynamically-filter-content-using-checkboxes-jquery) i have created a filter (which i dint knew previously :) ) but still not able to filter as expected.... [**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/R3tVq/1/)

**HTML :**

```
<!-- HTML filter chkboxes -->
<input type="checkbox" id="wm" class="a" />WM
<input type="checkbox" id="tv" class="a" />tv
<input type="checkbox" id="ac" class="a" />ac
<input type="checkbox" id="terrace" class="a" />terrace


<!-- Values to be filetered -->
<div class="wm">WM</div>
<div class="tv">TV</div>
<div class="ac">ac</div>
<div class="terrace">terrace</div>
<div class="wm tv">WM TV</div>
<div class="wm tv ac">wm tv ac</div>
<div class="wm terrace">wm terrace</div>
<div class="tv">tv</div>
<div class="tv ac">tv ac</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".a").change(function () {
        $("." + this.id).toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

**What was your problem again????:** though i have mentioned it in fiddle but for quick reader..... i am able to hide the unchecked filter values, but they disappear even if they have some `class` whose filter has been checked to view like `<div class="wm tv">WM TV</div>`

I don't want ajax or some rocket-science jQuery to sort this out....looking for some simple solution considering a noob asked it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in the first link you posted:

> Hide all  elements, then loop through the checkboxes and for each
>   checked one .show() the  elements with the associated category.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".a").change(function () {
        $('div').hide(); //hide all elements
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() { //loop through checked checkboxes
            $("." + this.id).show(); //show
        });
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tVq/2/)

Comment: Upvoted....this works as expected...gr8.....one mini-question...assuming i remove `$('div').hide();` then why do they fail to work....will this work only on hidden elements and not when content is visible by-default?

Comment: @Mayank The problem is the function `.toggle` – this method will hide unwanted elements, just as you describe your problem.

Comment: `$('div').hide()` is required because we're only `show`ing elements on `checked` event. We must also hide other elements that don't have the classes for checked checkboxes. This doesn't rely on the initial visibility of elements; you can remove the explicit triggering of `change()` from the fiddle.

Comment: It will also hide the `<div class="msg">` element - which is not one of the ones which is supposed to be hidden.

Comment: @MT0 : agreed...noticed that....`@all` : to show the `div`'s by default, i tried this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/R3tVq/4/) and hid the `unchecked` boxes on check on filtering...but its not working...shall i create a new thread for this prob or can it be resolved in comments itself!!!

Comment: My answer doesn't have this issue - alternatively you can apply the same changes I've done to the `HTML` to this answer and instead of doing `$('div').hide();` do `$('div.item').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

I've added an 'item' class to each of the `DIV` tags you want to toggle to make it easier to select them all but other than that I've left the `HTML` alone.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3w63F/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var a = $('.a'),items=$('.item');
     a.change(function () {
         var classes = a.filter( ':checked' ).map( function() { return this.id; } );
         items.each( function(){
             var t = $( this );
             for ( var i in classes )
             {
                 if ( t.hasClass( classes[i] ) )
                 {
                     t.show();
                     return;
                 }
             }
             t.hide();
         });
    }).change();
});
```

The `a.filter( ':checked' )` will filter the list of checkboxes to only those which are checked and then `.map()` will take each checked checkbox and apply the given function to it returning an array containing the results of that function - in this case, the function passed extracts the value of the `id` attribute so you will end up with an array of the `id` attributes of the checked checkboxes.

The `items.each()` iterates over each of the elements you want to show/hide and tests each one to see if it has one of the (previously found) classes and, if so, shows it and if it has none of the classes then hides it.