# Hide non required results through filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

**Where it all began :** I have already asked one question on filters here : [Filter result using jquery or JS from an existing value set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349924/filter-result-using-jquery-or-js-from-an-existing-value-set#20350413)

**Problem :**
Since the data is coming from another page through a `form post`, all values are supposed to be visible at first......so user can go through that data and if required, he has the priviledge to use filters to sort out the requirement.

**what's making me feel like a train-wreck**
is that the values (to be filtered) on page are supposed to be visible by default and then when user clicks on say `class="tv"`, all other `div classes` which do not contain `tv` should hide

**Where i am stucked???**
I tried to work out a jQuery which i thought was correct logically but the result made me believe otherwise :(

**Problem with previous question**
My previous question helped in filtering...but the data was `hide()` by default...i needed reverse....

**Effort and Fiddle??**
**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/r6g3k/1/

**HTML**

```
<!-- filter checkboxes -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="wm" class="a" />WM
    <input type="checkbox" id="tv" class="a" />tv
    <input type="checkbox" id="ac" class="a" />ac
    <input type="checkbox" id="terrace" class="a" />terrace


    <br> <hr><br>

   <!-- Results to be filtered -->
    <div class="wm field">WM</div>
    <div class="tv field">TV</div>
    <div class="ac field">ac</div>
    <div class="terrace field">terrace</div>
    <div class="wm tv field">WM TV</div>
    <div class="wm tv ac field">wm tv ac</div>
    <div class="wm terrace field">wm terrace</div>
    <div class="tv field">tv</div>
    <div class="tv ac field">tv ac</div>
```

my noob **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.field').show(); // to show values by default


    $(".a").change(function () {
        $('div').hide(); //hide before displaying
        $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            $("." + this.id).hide(); //hide unchecked filter values
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this might be easier**

```
var puts = $('.a');//get checkboxes
var cans = $('.field');//get content
puts.on('change', function() {//when checkbox changes
    if (!puts.filter(':checked').length) {//if nothing's checked
        cans.show();//show it all
    } else {//if something's checked
        cans.hide();//hide all
        puts.filter(':checked').each(function() {//get checked
            $('.'+this.id+':hidden').show();//show if hidden
        });  
    }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/F8Vk2/

**breakdown**

`puts` is the checkboxes

`cans` is the content blocks

When a checkbox state changes, if nothing is currently checked it shows everything. If something is checked it hides all content blocks and shows any that have a class that matches the `id` of a checked box. It only shows things that are hidden, so it doesn't have to run show multiple times on content blocks that apply to multiple checked boxes.

Comment: first...its hell complex to understand....second if `WM` is selected...i should see `WM` - `WM TV` - `wm tv` - `ac wm terrace`...and thats not happening.....thoughts?? :)

Comment: refactored everything and simplified it, still too complex?